# Is there a 'format painter' function in Excel for Android?

Tags: microsoft-excel

is there a 'format painter' function in Excel for Android? I'm starting to feel like you get what you pay for here - not much, by that, I mean, that the Android version of Excel is short on features that I find useful.

Comment: Check this out... https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_amobile-mso_mobapps/wordexcel-for-android/994e0673-930a-43a6-8952-66416745d9ae

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've been able to come, is:

1. Click on the cell with the formatting I like, then long click on the little square bottom right of the cell, and release, then click on the clipboard icon.
2. Click on the cell I want to format, and long click on the square, bottom right of the cell, and  release again, this time, click on the downward facing arrow, and choose "Formatting".  It works, but much more awkward than the format painter function in the Windows versions of Excel. (and Word)

If anyone has a way to be able to do this quicker, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard copy and paste function. Copy the cell with the format you want. Then paste on the desired cell using "special paste", then select "paste format" only. This pastes just the format, not the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit the "Copy" icon.

   [image]

   *(Click on image to enlarge)*
2. Long click on the target cell.
3. Instead of the "Paste" icon (clipboard), click the drop-down arrow.

   [image]

   *(Click on image to enlarge)*
4. Click on "Formatting" (paintbrush icon)

   [image]

   *(Click on image to enlarge)*
5. Should have copied the format successfully!